# ASP.Net error: "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted." after lengthy delay in page usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I've got a Search page in a C#/ASP.Net app.  The search functionality works flawlessly.  However, if a user uses the search functionality and then, say, minimizes the page and comes back an hour or two later and resubmits the search without refreshing the page, they get this error:

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is
>   invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: The serialized data is invalid.]
>   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(Stream inputStream)
>   +12060132    System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose) +679
>   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter,
>   String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +67
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +200
>
> [ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.
>
> ```
>     Client IP: 10.55.105.238
>     Port: 62555
>     Referer: http://d-csttool/CSTTOOL/frmAuditSearch.aspx
>     Path: /CSTTOOL/frmAuditSearch.aspx
>     User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; 
>     Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
>     .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E;
>     InfoPath.3)
>     ViewState:
> ```
>
> > 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...]
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this
>   page and might be corrupted.]
>   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String
>   persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
>   +157    System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +12060917    System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +12316717
>   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +51
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +12309571    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +12309089    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +119    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +99
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +913    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

Any ideas on what could be causing this?  Is there some timeout type code I need to throw in here?  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the page hosted on a web farm or a cluster, that is, more than one server?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not positive.  I'm on the development end, the server guys take care of the servers, and we work in 3 different environments (Development, Testing and Production).  So it's probable the Dev environment isn't a cluster but the Prod environment is.

Comment: This is a common issue on a cluster setup.  It's because the user can roam between servers when POST-ing the form.  When that happens, the request/state validation fails because the key used to decrypt the state information is different than the key used to generate it.  One way to fix this is to give each server the same fixed machine key or by utilizing mechanisms present on most load balancers which makes sure that each client "sticks" to the same server for a given time (usually controlled with a cookie).

Comment: Try to use `GET` request to the search page instead of `POST` (if possible). Try to use **ASP.Net State Service**